# Classify areas of an image based on color

Tags: image-processing, python

I have some tree canopy images that I would like to process, but not sure how to get started as image processing is a little outside my area of expertise. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tree [canopy images](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3zhe2C8Pgm6WkJCNFBIQmE2MENYUkJfTU1ERTFaZE1tMnBr/view?usp=sharing) with a grid included in the image.

[image]

I have converted the image to a five color [palette](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3zhe2C8Pgm6Y2FiX1FtMWVpczc0ZjFrRl9INmFQMnM4Skt3/view?usp=sharing) so that sky is easily distinguished from tree cover.

[image]

I would like to overlay a series of boxes that line up with the grid (basically a small box under the numbers) and estimate the percentage of pixels within the box that are the "sky" color.

I am not envisioning that this would be fully automated. The workflow would be:

1. classify image to five color palette,
2. by hand overlay boxes from a separate file so that the boxes match up with grid in image,
3. loop through boxes and estimate percentage of underlying colors.

I can code in Python and R, but haven't ever used them to process images.

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  Is there any chance you can share an example image? That might help get answers.

Comment: Sure. What is the preferred method of sharing an image?

Comment: OK. I've inlined the images. Let's see if we get some answers.

Comment: Your palettization of the image looks very effective. What are you still missing ?

Comment: Am I right to think that the grid is fixed with respect to the cover window, so that all you need is to locate and orient this cover ?

Comment: the grid is fixed and part of the image. I need to create a separate grid with small boxes that overlays (but doesn't include the original grid) so that I can classify the boxes.

Comment: And ? What is blocking you ?

Comment: I don't know how to take a series of boxes, overlay on the image, and get the percentage estimates of the colors included in the box.